# JAX-RS Jersey/Grizzly Define an interface resource

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, grizzly

Following the example [here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e53) On deploying a sample resource using the Grizzly container.
It uses a resource that is defined as a class, instead I would like to define an interface with the annotations and have the resource class implements that interface.

The problem now is that Grizzly complains that it can't find the resource:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not     contain any root resource classes.
```

On Main class, where "com.mycompany.pack" is the package containing the implementation class:

```
final String baseUri = "http://localhost:9999/";
final Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.mycompany.pack");
```

[Edit]: It works however when adding the annotations on the class as well.
If there is a way to have the annotations declared only at the interface level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with package scanning because that only looks for classes with the JAX-RS annotations on them. You'll have to use a different approach: either one of the [configuration options](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/1.9.1/user-guide.html#d4e196) mentioned in the Jersey user guide that lets you explicitly declare your resource classes, or you could also use [jersey-spring](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/jersey_and_spring) to manage your instances. With jersey-spring, there are no extra steps to be able to use an interface like you want to. You just annotate the interface, make the implementation a Spring bean, and it works.

Comment: has this changed with jersey 2?

Comment: I don't know much about Jersey 2. I suggest asking a new question if you still want to know about it.