# Support for annotation inheritance in Jersey

Tags: rest, annotations, jersey

I am working on creating a SOA project. I want to use Jersey to expose the services on rest. In my project the standard is to create a API project which has API interfaces and DTOs. The implementation project depends on the API project and all implementation is written in the implementation.

The idea behind this architecture is that, we could create two API projects one for REST and other for SOAP, annotate the interfaces with required annotations. As a result the implementation would be unaware about the method used to expose the service (I mean REST and SOAP).

But the problem in Jersey is unable to discover the annotations on the interface and keeps throwing following exception

> ```
> com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
> ```

A similar question has already been asked - [JAX-RS Jersey/Grizzly Define an interface resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727747/jax-rs-jersey-grizzly-define-an-interface-resource) - The answer says that it is possible using Spring-Jersey.

But I tried various configuration options for spring-jersey - including - http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.8/contribs/jersey-spring/com/sun/jersey/spi/spring/container/servlet/package-summary.html

But did not have any success.

Questions

1. The idea of trying to manage the different ways of exposing service thru interface, is it a feasible and good idea? How are experts in the industry doing?
2. How can I manage to use Jersey to understand the annotations done on Interface?
3. Is some other framework like RestEasy going to help?

Comment: Questions 2 and 3 are resolved, I successfully achieved this configuration using http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/.